# Increasing speed of copying into Word from Excel and saving document

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I have some code that loops through rows, finds a desired area to copy, copies it to Word and then saves it as a "txt" file.  It works fine but is rather slow when running on full size samples where it is creating 80+ files.  I believe this is because the code below is opening and closing Word every time it runs rather than leave it open but I'm not sure how to get it to stay open and create new documents.  Is there a way to do that or another way to speed the code up?

```
Set wrdapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wrdapp.Visible = False

Set wrddoc = wrdapp.Documents.Add
Rows(endingrow + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Cells(endingrow + 1, "A").Value = "%"
Rows(startingrow).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Cells(startingrow, "A").Value = "%"
endingrow = endingrow + 2
Range(Cells(startingrow, "A"), Cells(endingrow, "A")).Copy

With wrdapp
.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
.Visible = True
.Selection.WholeStory
End With

With wrdapp.Selection.ParagraphFormat
    .SpaceBefore = 0
    .SpaceBeforeAuto = False
    .SpaceAfter = 0
    .SpaceAfterAuto = False
    .LineUnitBefore = 0
End With

wrdapp.ChangeFileOpenDirectory GetFolder
wrdapp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 filename:=filename, FileFormat:= _
wdFormatText, LockComments:=False, Password:="", AddToRecentFiles _
:=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, EmbedTrueTypeFonts _
:=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData:=False, _
SaveAsAOCELetter:=False
wrdapp.Quit
```

Comment: You can write directly to `.txt` file instead of using `Word` as intermediary. [One example](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/write-data-to-text-file.html) of how to do it.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I'll give that a shot tomorrow.  I've been reading about that and didn't see any mention of inserting a whole block of text so it looks like I will need to loop through each row and insert in which may not be faster.  Each text file is about 400 lines (rows) so it may work.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to continue doing this in MS Word and save as a text file, there are a few things to be aware of...

1 - You've created a `wrdDoc` but don't seem to use it.

2 - You can replace this:

```
With wrdapp
  .Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
  .Visible = True
  .Selection.WholeStory
End With
```

with this:

`wrdDoc.Range.Paste`

3 - You don't really need this if you're saving as a text file...

```
With wrdapp.Selection.ParagraphFormat
  .SpaceBefore = 0
  .SpaceBeforeAuto = False
  .SpaceAfter = 0
  .SpaceAfterAuto = False
  .LineUnitBefore = 0
End With
```

4 - And finally, to close the document and leave the application open you can do this: `wrdDoc.Close` *(i.e. use the document you created)* instead of  `wrdapp.Quit` *(shutting down the Word application)*

All that aside, yes you can write directly to text file as suggested by @ScottHoltzman